# If you are using `Sequelize`, is there a way to process it when calling the data?

Tags: sequelize.js

When I call `Product` with findOne or findAll, I always want to change it to * 30% to the value already specified in the table.

Is there a way to change the value stored in the table only when the Model is called without changing it?

Model

```js
const {
  Model,
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Product extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Plan.belongsTo(models.Supplier);
      Plan.hasMany(models.Order, {
        foreignKey: "productId",
      });
    }
  }
  Product.init({
    price: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Product",
  });
  return Product;
};
```

Comment: Its solved. I used `get()` to each `init()` function

Comment: If you solved the problem, consider adding the solution as an answer to help other users identify this question as already answered.

Comment: I got it!. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using aggregation in attributes. For example -

```
 Product.findAll({
 attributes: [
 [Sequelize.literal('(price*3)'), 'newPrice']
 ]
 });
```

*Please take special care while using `sequelize.literal` because it inserts arbitrary input without escaping to the query, it should not be used on user-generated content.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer!

```
const {
  Model,
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Product extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Product.belongsTo(models.Supplier);
      Product.hasMany(models.Order, {
        foreignKey: "productId",
      });
    }
  }
  Product.init({
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      get() {
        // If you want to add 10%
        return this.dataValues * 1.1
      },
      row: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Product",
  });
  return Product;
};
```